# Select contents of div to fadeIn sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure the best way to word this, so hopefully this makes sense.

Currently, on my page, all my elements fadeIn on click. What I would like is for a few select elements in an id (#seqFade below) to fade in on their own when that parent fadeIn class is clicked.

I've figured out how to make both of these effects work on separate pages, but I can't figure out how to have them both occur on the same page / combine the two.

Here is more or less how my page is designed, and below is what I have so far for code.

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">

   <div class="fadeIn">
      <p>Hello</p>
   </div>

   <div class="fadeIn" id="seqFade">
        <span>1</span>
        <span>2</span>
        <span>3</span>
    </div>

    <div class="fadeIn">
       Bye.
    </div>

</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

//hides all fadeIns 
    $('.fadeIn').hide();

$(document).on('click',function() {
    if('#seqFade') {
//sequential fadeIn function (works)
          $('span').each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay(i*300).fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }

//fadeIn on click (works)
   $('.fadeIn:hidden:first').fadeIn('slow');
})
.click();
```

Thank you so much in advance.

[JSfiddle of full page](http://jsfiddle.net/tuckyeah/f2emw0q9/2/) // 
[JSFiddle of both effects working](http://jsfiddle.net/tuckyeah/h67vk02w/1/)

Comment: Giving a jsfiddle would make it easier for us to show you what to do.

Comment: do you have any css?

Comment: On my page, I have css defining the larger 'content' div, but i've also seen that this effect might be possible through css only

Comment: and actually your code works fine just need to say #seqFade p instead of just #seqFade

Answer (score 0):

Use the classes for this (add some fade/noFade classes to elements). ID must be unique. And after that just check if the element has that class like this. Now you have basically unlimited options to do this. Just add more classes / check and do something.

```
$(".class_of_element").hasClass("your_class")
```

Comment: i tried it here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tuckyeah/5nqtv66s/2/) but now the seqFade isn't showing up at all...

Comment: Hello. Just add # before myDiv if($('#myDiv').hasClass('seqFade')) { id = "#" class = "."

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
   <div id="content">

   <div class="fadeIn">
      <p>Hello</p>
   </div>

   <div class="fadeIn" id="seqFade">
        <span>L</span>
        <span>o</span>
        <span>a</span>
        <span>d</span>
        <span>i</span>
        <span>n</span>
        <span>g</span>
        <span>.</span>
        <span>.</span>
        <span>.</span>
    </div>

    <div class="fadeIn" id="bye">
       Bye.
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {

    $('.fadeIn').find('span').toggle();
    $('#hello, #bye').toggle();

    $(document).click(function() {
        $('#hello').fadeIn('slow');
        $('span').each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay(i*300).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                $(document).unbind('click')
                           .bind('click', () => $('#bye').delay(300).fadeIn('slow'));
            });
        });
    });

});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mLgu3om/3/

Or like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just add a class on hidden at the beginning for the spans

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var timeOuts = new Array();
            var eT=200;
            function myFadeIn(jqObj) {
                jqObj.fadeIn('slow');
            }
            function clearAllTimeouts() {
                for (key in timeOuts) {
                    clearTimeout(timeOuts[key]);
                }
            }
            $(document).on('click',function() {
            $('#seqFade span').hide().each(function(index) {
                timeOuts[index] = setTimeout(myFadeIn, index*eT, $(this));
            });
            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h67vk02w/2/